# How to decorate a custom member on LINQ To SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, data-binding

I want to create a property on my LINQ To SQL designer-generated class that gets and sets a formatted type, like that:

```
public partial ALinqClass
{
    public string formatedValue
    {
       get { return formatValue(TheValue); }
       set { TheValue = RemoveFormating(value); }
    }
}
```

TheValue is the property generated by the Linq designer.

How do I decorate `public string formatedValue` so I can bind it to controls on my form?
For example: When I use Visual Studio to create a Object Data Source from my linq object/class all properties linq generated are present on the Object data Source, but formatedValue is not.

Why ?

WHY ?

WHHHHHHHHY ????????!!!!!

Thank you.

Fábio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq-to-SQL generated entities are declared as partial classes so you should be able to create another file and add custom properties to the same partial class. This is so if you have to regenerate the classes, your additions to the entities are still available in a different file.

Also as long as these properties are public, you should be able to databind them just like generated properties.

Comment: Thats what I Did. On aother file i decrared a the partial class and created the property as shown above. Problem is I cant get it to show on the IDE and use it to bind it to a control. I can use it on linq queries but i wanted it to show on the IDE and to ber able to bind to it.

Comment: @Fabio is this winforms or wpf? what kind of control is it that you are trying to databind to this custom property?

Comment: This is windows forms. I´m trying to bind a textbox. The problem i´m trying to solve is to strip formating to save on the database but show format when databound.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Forms Databinding, you need either

- A datasource, which is derived from `Control`.
- An intermediate component, `BindingSource`, acting as link between the LinqToSql datasource and bound controls.

I'll outline how to use `BindingSource`.

```
private BindingSource binding1;
private YourDataContext context;

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // initialize the data context
     context = new YourDataContext();
    // initialize the BindingSource
    binding1 = new BindingSource();
    binding1.DataSource = context.YourObjects;
    // bind controls to BindingSource
    listBox1.DataSource = binding1;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
}
```

Obviously, this short sample is not complete, but should give you an idea on how to start. Further information can be found at [Data Binding and Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k(v=VS.100).aspx).

Mark

Comment: Please note the question: How do I decorate public string formatedValue so I can bind it to controls on my form? What do I have to do so a property will became a bindable property. I know it is as simple as using a atribute, or, as people say, decorate the property using [ and ] before the declaration. I Think I have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer I wanted. Linq must have a few more classes and inheritances, but I think this will do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute.aspx

```
[Bindable(true)]
 public int MyProperty 
 {
    get {
       // Insert code here.
       return 0;
        }

    set {
       // Insert code here.
        }
 }
```

Comment: OK, this does not work. it works for Plain classes but not with linq classes. Well, back to the drawing board.